# Fontpath is not passed through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app there is an activity say Activity A which has an image view with some text views. code is listed below

```
    public class EidCardFinal extends Activity {

        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView receiver, sender, messagebody;
        private Intent intent;
        private Bundle bundle;
        private static final int FONT_SELECT = 1;

        // public String filepath = "MyFileStorage";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_eid_card_final);
            intent = getIntent();
            String message1 = intent.getStringExtra("RECEIVER");
            String message2 = intent.getStringExtra("SENDER");
            String message3 = intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGEBODY");
            String check_click = intent.getStringExtra("bttnclick");
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            receiver = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            sender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            messagebody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            receiver.setText(message1);
            sender.setText(message2);
            messagebody.setText(message3);

            // Selected image id
            if ("BUTTONCLICK".equals(check_click)) {
                String path = intent.getStringExtra("image");
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse(path);
                imageView.setImageURI(myUri);

            } else {
                int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
                ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

                // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.thumbIds[position]);


    case R.id.change_fonts:
                Intent fontintent = new Intent();
                bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                fontintent.putExtras(bundle);
                fontintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), FontSelection.class);
                this.startActivityForResult(fontintent, FONT_SELECT);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == FONT_SELECT) {
                Bundle pathadd= data.getExtras();
                String fontadd = pathadd.getString("FONTPATH");

                //intent = getIntent();
                /*String message1 = data.getStringExtra("RECEIVER");
                String message2 = data.getStringExtra("SENDER");
                String message3 = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGEBODY");
                //String check_click = intent.getStringExtra("bttnclick");
                imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                receiver = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                sender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                messagebody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                receiver.setText(message1);
                sender.setText(message2);
                messagebody.setText(message3);*/

                //bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                Typeface tyfa = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontadd);
                receiver.setTypeface(tyfa);
                sender.setTypeface(tyfa);
                messagebody.setTypeface(tyfa);
                s


}
    }
}
```

From menu, user is taken to another activity say Activity B from where a custom font can be selected for Activity A. Code is listed below

```
public class FontSelection extends Activity {



String[] fontpath = { "fonts/android_7.ttf", "fonts/doridrobot.ttf",
        "fonts/droidsansmono.ttf", "fonts/droidserif-bold.ttf",
        "fonts/green-avocado.ttf", "fonts/lokicola.ttf",
        "fonts/outwrite.ttf", "fonts/painting-the-light.ttf",
        "fonts/roboto-black.ttf", "fonts/roboto-boldcondensed.ttf",
        "fonts/roboto-medium.ttf", "fonts/roboto-regular.ttf" };

String[] fontname = { "android_7", "doridrobot", "droidsansmono",
        "droidserif-bold", "green-avocado", "lokicola", "outwrite",
        "painting-the-light", "roboto-black", "roboto-boldcondensed",
        "roboto-medium", "roboto-regular" };

private Intent fontpathintent = new Intent();
private Bundle bundle1;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_font_selection);

    RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[0]);
    radio1.setTypeface(tf1);
    radio1.setText(fontname[0]);

    RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[1]);
    radio2.setTypeface(tf2);
    radio2.setText(fontname[1]);

    RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    Typeface tf3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[2]);
    radio3.setTypeface(tf3);
    radio3.setText(fontname[2]);

    RadioButton radio4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
    Typeface tf4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[3]);
    radio4.setTypeface(tf4);
    radio4.setText(fontname[3]);

    RadioButton radio5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
    Typeface tf5 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[4]);
    radio5.setTypeface(tf5);
    radio5.setText(fontname[4]);

    RadioButton radio6 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton6);
    Typeface tf6 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[5]);
    radio6.setTypeface(tf6);
    radio6.setText(fontname[5]);

    RadioButton radio7 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton7);
    Typeface tf7 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[6]);
    radio7.setTypeface(tf7);
    radio7.setText(fontname[6]);

    RadioButton radio8 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton8);
    Typeface tf8 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[7]);
    radio8.setTypeface(tf8);
    radio8.setText(fontname[7]);

    RadioButton radio9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);
    Typeface tf9 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[8]);
    radio9.setTypeface(tf9);
    radio9.setText(fontname[8]);

    RadioButton radio10 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton10);
    Typeface tf10 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[9]);
    radio10.setTypeface(tf10);
    radio10.setText(fontname[9]);

    RadioButton radio11 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton11);
    Typeface tf11 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[10]);
    radio11.setTypeface(tf11);
    radio11.setText(fontname[10]);

    RadioButton radio12 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton12);
    Typeface tf12 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath[11]);
    radio12.setTypeface(tf12);
    radio12.setText(fontname[11]);

}

public void onRadioButtonClick(View view) {

    bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.radioButton1:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[0]);

        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton2:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[1]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton3:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[2]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton4:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[3]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton5:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[4]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton6:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[5]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton7:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[6]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton8:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[7]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton9:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[8]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton10:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[9]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton11:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[10]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton12:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[11]);
        fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        startActivity(fontpathintent);
        break;
    }
}
```

my problem is, upon selection of font, there is no change in activity A, i mean font in activity A remains unchanged.

changed the code, but still no luck

```
case R.id.radioButton1:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[0]);

        // fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        // fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        // startActivity(fontpathintent);
        setResult(1, fontpathintent);
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton2:
        if (checked)
            fontpathintent.putExtra("FONTPATH", fontpath[1]);
        // fontpathintent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),EidCardFinal.class);
        // fontpathintent.putExtras(bundle1);
        // startActivity(fontpathintent);
        setResult(1, fontpathintent);
        finish();
        break;

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // Bundle pathadd= data.getExtras();
            String customfont = data.getStringExtra("FONTPATH");
            // String fontadd = pathadd.getString("FONTPATH");

            // intent = getIntent();
            /*
             * String message1 = data.getStringExtra("RECEIVER"); String
             * message2 = data.getStringExtra("SENDER"); String message3 =
             * data.getStringExtra("MESSAGEBODY"); //String check_click =
             * intent.getStringExtra("bttnclick"); imageView = (ImageView)
             * findViewById(R.id.imageView1); receiver = (TextView)
             * findViewById(R.id.textView1); sender = (TextView)
             * findViewById(R.id.textView2); messagebody = (TextView)
             * findViewById(R.id.textView3); receiver.setText(message1);
             * sender.setText(message2); messagebody.setText(message3);
             */

            // bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            Typeface tyfa = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    customfont);
            receiver.setTypeface(tyfa);
            sender.setTypeface(tyfa);
            messagebody.setTypeface(tyfa);

        }
```

i think there is some problem while calling onActivityResult() as i have tried below line of code, but no result as well. can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

```
tyfa = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "fonts/outwrite.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. Actually i was using requestCode instead of resultcode in setResult(), and that was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

use another field and give each item with unique id then use getextra and putextra methods may be it will help

Answer (score 0):

You should not start the first activity again, instead of that you should set results of the secont activity and close it. The first activity will then get the results in the `onActivityResult` method.

Here is an [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example) how that works